# R: Transform values from one row to a a enumeration one below the other

Tags: r

Let's assume the data set is of the following form:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value | Value | Value | Value | Value | Value |
| Value | Value | Value | Value | Value | Value |
| Value | Value | Value | Value | Value | Value |

I would like to have the values of columns B, C and D as well as D, E and F, which were previously in one line, one below the other, each with a label ("Tag" column) so that I can select them later:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value | Value | Value | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Value | Value | Value | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Value | Value | Value | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | Value | Value | Value | 2 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | Value | Value | Value | 2 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | Value | Value | Value | 2 |

I wonder if there is any 'smooth' of performing this transition bc I will have to do this multiple times for large datasets. I know I could extract the columns A to C and D to F to an empty dataset manually and then
`rbind`  them, but I dont think thats an effective way.

Answer (score 1):

We could do

```
library(Matrix)
lst1 <- lapply(split.default(df1,
    rep(1:2, each = 3)), as.matrix)
out <- transform( as.data.frame.matrix(bdiag(lst1)),
     Tag = rep(names(lst1), each = nrow(df1)))
names(out) <- c(names(df1), "Tag")
```

-output

```
> out
      ColumnA    ColumnB      ColumnC    ColumnD    ColumnE     ColumnF Tag
1 -0.72539184 -1.1483602 -0.008719768  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.00000000   1
2 -0.05808885 -0.2167649  0.015604732  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.00000000   1
3  0.53870107  1.7174522  0.336478920  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.00000000   1
4  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.000000000 -0.8776873 -0.6020000  0.01259945   2
5  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.000000000 -0.7657040 -0.7159904 -1.06291396   2
6  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.000000000  0.1971328  0.6296312  0.53238059   2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ColumnA = c(-0.725391839226287, -0.0580888549810791, 
0.538701074659855), ColumnB = c(-1.14836015215428, -0.216764874522502, 
1.71745221052422), ColumnC = c(-0.00871976805731077, 0.0156047319685544, 
0.336478919846347), ColumnD = c(-0.877687329669588, -0.765703953952569, 
0.197132783238087), ColumnE = c(-0.602000029378949, -0.715990446890288, 
0.629631228296845), ColumnF = c(0.0125994532627825, -1.06291395852758, 
0.532380586621345)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Looks really nice. But this only works for my (symmetric) example, right? In fact, I often have a dataset of for example 24 columns, from which column 4-12 equal A-C in my example and columns 13-22 which are equal to D-F.

Comment: @TOm_99 Not clear from the comments.  If you have 24 columns, and each should be split in 3, the `rep(1:2, each = 3)` should be changed to `rep(1:8, each = 3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

equal_columns <- list(1:3, 4:6)
df1 %>%
   split.default(rep(seq(equal_columns), lengths(equal_columns))) %>%
   bind_rows()%>%
   replace(is.na(.), 0)

      ColumnA    ColumnB      ColumnC    ColumnD    ColumnE     ColumnF
1 -0.72539184 -1.1483602 -0.008719768  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
2 -0.05808885 -0.2167649  0.015604732  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
3  0.53870107  1.7174522  0.336478920  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
4  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.000000000 -0.8776873 -0.6020000  0.01259945
5  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.000000000 -0.7657040 -0.7159904 -1.06291396
6  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.000000000  0.1971328  0.6296312  0.53238059
```